# Hojas de Estilo con Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Buen día a todos, quisiera preguntar algo sobre la siguiente instrucción de Laravel:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
```

Como veís, estoy usando el helper "asset" pero este no funciona correctamente, sin embargo, cuando cambio la linea por la siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Esta si carga correctamente, no se si algo cambió en la version de Laravel 7 o algo, pero leyendome la documentación no encuentro nada, quisiera saber como hacer para que funcione con el helper, muchas gracias de ante mano

Comment: ¿Cuando usas la primer opción aparece algún error en la consola?

Comment: Me tira muchas advertencias de este tipo: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7B%20asset('asset/plugins/parallax-js-master/parallax.min.js')%20%7D%7D”.

Comment: Considera editar y agregar los mensajes de error, precisamente esos ayudarán a identificar el problema

Comment: Solo quiero saber cual sería la sintaxis para usar bien el asset para importar una hoja de estilo...

Comment: La sintaxis es esa misma que estás usando. Ese no es el problema. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset

Comment: El error que muestras en el comentario es de por tratar de incorporar un script con la etiqueta `link`, yo utilizo `asset` en la versión 7 de laravel sin ningún problema.